# Is there a Z-Index within a SSRS Chart?

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008

I have a chart with 3 data series, 2 are columns and 1 is a line. Is there a way I can influence how they are displayed on the z-axis(z-index) ? Basically I want to have influence what is displayed on top of what.
On the report itself I can influence the different items, however within a chart I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Chart series items do not have a Z-Index property. Although I have found that the sort order of the series groups directly affect the z-index order. Once sorted, the first series is rendered on top and the last series is rendered on the bottom.

If you edit the series group properties:

[image: Series Group Properties]

Then go to the "Sorting" tab, you can choose which column it sorts by. In my case, I added an extra column in my DataSet which keeps track of the order I want. I chose to sort on that:

[image: Sorting]

Comment: I will give this a try, hope for the next release MSFT will get such basics included.

Comment: Let's hope! It would be really nice.

Answer (score 2):

Reorder the series in the "Values" box.

It seems those near the top of the list are rendered first, with each subsequent series rendered 'on top' of those already rendered. So the order of the series in the "Values" box appears to simulate a z-index through order of rendering.